# Import and show file content in MDX code blocks

Tags: reactjs, markdown, jsx, mdx, docusaurus

I'm using Docusaurus to build doc. Docusaurus use MDX.
I would like to show a .json file in the doc using a [code block](https://docusaurus.io/docs/markdown-features/code-blocks) without needing to copy/past the file content.

Instead of writting this in my md doc:

```markdown
Let see the content of the `helloworld.json` file :
'''json title="helloworld.json"
{
  "hello":"world"
}
'''
```

I would like to have a `asserts/helloworld.json` file and do something like:

```markdown
Let see the content of the `helloworld.json` file :
'''json title="helloworld.json" from "asserts/helloworld.json"
'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the guide here: https://docusaurus.io/docs/markdown-features/react#importing-code-snippets

You can import code snippets as raw-text React components and add these to code blocks.